# Examine data at in callout driver for FWPM_LAYER_EGRESS_VSWITCH_TRANSPORT_V4 layer in WFP

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, hyper-v, wfp

I am writing the callout driver for Hyper-V 2012 where I need to filter the packets sent from virtual machines.

I added filter at FWPM_LAYER_EGRESS_VSWITCH_TRANSPORT_V4 layer in WFP. Callout function receive packet buffer which I am typecasting it to NET_BUFFER_LIST. I am doing following to get the data pointer

pNetBuffer = NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB((NET_BUFFER_LIST*)pClassifyData->pPacket);
pContiguousData = NdisGetDataBuffer(pNetBuffer, NET_BUFFER_DATA_LENGTH(pNetBuffer), 0, 1, 0);

I have simple client-server application to test the packet data. Client is on VM and server is another machine. As I observed, data sent from client to server is truncated and some garbage value is added at the end. There is no issue for sending message from server to client. If I dont add this layer filter client-server works without any issue.

Callback function receives the metadata which incldues ipHeaderSize and transportHeaderSize. Both these values are zero. Are these correct values or should those be non-zero??
Can somebody help me to extract the data from packet in callout function and forward it safely to further layers?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

These are the TCP packets. I looked into size and offset information. It seems the problem is consistent across packets. 
I checked below values in (NET_BUFFER_LIST*)pClassifyData->pPacket.

NET_BUFFER_LIST->NetBUfferListHeader->NetBUfferListData->FirstNetBuffer->NetBuffe rHeader->NetBufferData->CurrentMdl->MappedSystemVa

First 24 bytes are only sent correctly and remaining are garbage.

For example total size of the packet is 0x36 + 0x18 = 0x4E I don't know what is there in first 0x36 bytes which is constant for all the packets. Is it a TCP/IP header? Second part 0x18 is the actual data which i sent.

I even tried with API NdisQueryMdl() to retrieve from MDL list.

So on the receiver side I get only 24 bytes correct and remaining is the garbage. How to read the full buffer from NET_BUFFER_LIST?